# Simple command line todo-list

Tags: haskell

#### Introduction

I've written a simple command line todo-list in Haskell.

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/LightAndLight/haskell-todo). However, given people's time constraints, I have selected three verbose functions for review.

#### Function One

```
program :: StateT TodoList IO ()
program = do
    StateT $ \xs -> do
        (choice,_) <- runStateT requestChoice xs
        (_,xs') <- runStateT (parseChoice choice) xs
        runStateT printList xs'
        runStateT program xs'

main = runStateT program []
```

**Questions:**

- Am I repeating myself too much by extracting the monads using `runStateT`?
- Is there a better way to structure the main program?

#### Function Two

```
parseChoice :: Text -> StateT TodoList IO ()
parseChoice choice
    | first == "add" = addItem $ TodoItem second third
    | first == "remove" = removeItem $ parseInt second
    | first == "save" = saveList second
    | first == "load" = loadList second
    | first == "quit" = StateT $ \_ -> exitSuccess
    | otherwise = invalidChoice first
    where   args =  split (=='|') (toLower choice)
        first = head args
        second = if length args > 1 then args !! 1 else ""
        third = if length args > 2 then args !! 2 else ""
```

**Questions:**

- Am I using too many guards?

#### Function Three

```
removeItem :: Maybe Int -> StateT TodoList IO ()
removeItem mn = StateT remove
    where remove = \xs -> case mn of
        Just n -> if n <= length xs - 1 
            then return ((),removeAt n xs)
            else do
                S.putStrLn "Index too large"
                return ((),xs)
        Nothing -> do
            S.putStrLn "Invalid index entered"
            return ((),xs)
```

#### General Questions

- Which parts are un-idiomatic?
- Which parts are superfluous?
- Should I decompose these longer functions into smaller functions that do less?
- How else can I improve this code?

Comment: Hey would you like some help? This seems like an interesting project!

Comment: @SydKerckhove Sure, hit me up on Google+ and we'll discuss what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may not quite grasp the interplay between do-notation and monad transformer stacks. Take a look at how I've rewritten `program` here to leverage the actual machinery of `StateT`. The version you wrote is needlessly verbose due to your manually plumbing the state around!

```
program :: StateT TodoList IO ()
program = do
    choice <- requestChoice
    parseChoice choice
    printList
    program
```

`parseChoice` can be cleaned up by favoring pattern matching over guards. Whenever you see a wall of guards that depend only on `Eq`, consider pattern matching instead.

```
parseChoice :: Text -> StateT TodoList IO ()
parseChoice choice =
    case split (== '|') (toLower choice) of
        ["add", date, message] -> addItem $ TodoItem date message
        ["remove", index]      -> removeItem $ parseInt index
        ["save", file]         -> saveList file
        ["load", file]         -> loadList file
        ["quit"]               -> lift exitSuccess
        (invalid:_)            -> invalidChoice invalid
```

I think you can probably guess what can change about `removeItem` after reading my other changes now, so before reading this next code block try rewriting it on your own.

```
removeItem :: Maybe Int -> StateT TodoList IO ()
removeItem Nothing  = lift $ putStrLn "Invalid index entered"
removeItem (Just n) = modify (removeAt n)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise that `m >>= f` passed the result of running the `StateT` to `f` (I thought it passed the state). After perusing the source code I properly understand how to properly chain the transformer.

And might I add - Wow! How elegantly designed is this!? Bind practically ignores the inner monad! It works so well...

Comment: It's a chain of mapped functions. Of course it works ;-)